# do i need to declare my index.html in app.yaml?

Tags: python, google-app-engine-python, app.yaml

I am new to google app engine and have trouble configure my web app. I don't know what i do need to add to app.yaml and what i don't? for example i know that i have to add my static files like images, and style sheets , but what about scripts files like angular do i need to declare them as static as well.

NOTE: APP STRUCTURE 

+ProjectName

- app.yaml
- main.py
- resources

  - images
  - styles
  - scripts
  - index.html
- ```
   handlers:
   - url: /rescources/images/(.*)
   static_files: /images/\1
   upload: /rescources/images/.*


         - url: /rescources/styles
           static_dir: /rescources/styles

         - url: /rescources/scripts/.*
           static_dir: /rescources/scripts    

         - url: /.*
           script: main.APP

         libraries:
         - name: webapp2
           version: latest
         - name: jinja2
           version: latest
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your angular script files (if they are defined in a .js file) are to be considered static files. My suggestion is to move your images, css and script files (all .js files) into a seperate folder called 'static' and then your app.yaml file can be like below

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
    - url: /static
      static_dir: static

   - url: /.*
     script: main.APP

libraries:
   - name: webapp2
     version: latest
   - name: jinja2
     version: latest
```

If there's the possibility that your static files might change more frequently (for e.g. you've deployed your code to production but you're still working and making changes, you might want to set an explicit but lower expiration date for your static files. The example sets an expiration of 2 hours for your static files

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: "2h"
```

More details can be found here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_cache_expiration